# Delphi, EmbeddedWB/TWebbrowser - jQuery not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, delphi, internet-explorer, twebbrowser

I am using EmbeddedWB (A TWebbrowser extension) to do like a "live preview" of some dynamically generated content.

I am trying to add jQuery into the mix, so I can get some fancy effects going on, however since IE9 always asks "Allow blocked content" for each and every damn page, a dynamically generated one (Webbrowser.LoadFromString) certainly wont be allowed to have fun. To put it simple: It wont allow Javascript execution.

I tried adding a SecurityManager to my TEmbeddedWB, however that did not do it either. I tested my dynamic code in Firefox, and in IE9, and it works (of course, in IE9 I have to allow first, which was how I found it was a security issue).

Is there a painless way to get around this, without having to manually go into IE and tweak something? Or am I completely wrong about the cause of the issue?

**EDIT**: After trying [this article's method](http://www.fanhow.com/knowhow%3aAllow_Blocked_Content_in_Internet_Explorer_43798671), IE does not ask if it should allow stuff anymore, however my script is still not being executed within my TEmbeddedWB/TWebbrowser..

**EDIT 2**: Okay, by removing the jQuery code, and displaying a plain Alert, I am forced to conclude that JS is now being executed, however jQuery is not.

**EDIT 3**: Here is the (stripped down) HTML code that my app generates, where jQuery is not working in my EmbeddedWB/TWebbrowser control - **however**, it works in Internet Explorer 9 itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file://C:\jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <p>
      Some stuff here!
    </p>
    </center>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('I Am jQuery!!!!');
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT4**: I have also tried switching the `src` to a Google Hosted jQuery, and that did not work either. Removing the Metatag did not fix it either. Just letting you know of stuff I tried before you waste time on suggesting it :)

**EDIT5**: By navigating to a site that uses jQuery (Webbrowser.Navigate) the site was working as expected. However when doing it from my local test.html, or by doing `.LoadFromString();`, it will not work.

Will not work = jQuery code not executing.

Comment: is the magic meta tag required?

Comment: @mjn - Yes, to force the Webbrowser into IE9 mode, to enable CSS3 features.

Comment: @mjn - Removing it does not fix anything though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work if you use correct URL for the jquery.js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file://C:/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///jQuery.js"></script>
```

or a relative path, you can also omit the `file://` protocol:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jQuery.js"></script>
```

The above works when you load the HTML from a file. The question is however, if content from memory and javascript from file system is not considered crossing a security context boundary and rejected for that reason by the embedded browser. In that case, embedding jquery directly in the HTML content (using the `<script>` tag) should work.

Comment: Arent File locations usually with \'s? Will try now!

Comment: Here is my Script tag (has to use File://, because the HTML that is being loaded into the Webbrowser is not a file, but a string): <script type="text/javascript" src="file://C:/Users/Jeff/Documents/My Dropbox/Delphi Projects/My App/Live Preview/jQuery.js"></script>

Comment: I tried using /'s instead of \'s, and that did not show the alert either.

Comment: Yes, in case you load the HTML directly from memory I believe you have to use the full file:// spec. The URL should probably be correctly encoded, though: .../My%20Dropbox/... (maybe not, but try that). So does it work now?

Comment: The question is also, if content from memory and js from file system is not considered crossing a security context boundary and rejected for that reason by the embedded browser.

Comment: You could also try embedding the jquery directly into the html content.

Comment: Encoding the file URL did not do it either. I have tried loading the file using LoadFromFile, and that did not do it either.

Comment: Did you try inserting jquery directly into your html content with a `<script>` tag? That should work, at least.

Comment: Delphi does not like long strings. I just tried loading from a file instead in a HTML Editor app I made awhile ago, and in it you can select to view from file, or from stream, and when i do from File, jQuery message shows. However, loading from File in this app does not fix it. Will look into the other apps source now

Comment: you were right about the memory security conflict! LoadFromFile did not work, BUT using Navigate('file://...'); did!